# I have to calibrate the camera and 2D lidar and transform the coordinates from lidar to the camera coordinate. Has anyone any idea about it?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, lidar

I researched about projecting lidar points onto the camera image but when I try collecting cloud point data then, the amount of data is a lot and I don't have any idea about how to project these many data onto the image. It will be very helpful for my project if anyone can share the idea.

I have already found the camera's Intrinsic and extrinsic parameters using the Aruco marker as a reference point.
Also I have tried narrowing the lidar angle facing the Aruco marker to a certain angle so that the data collected will be comparatively less.